# Be wary of accepting edits that are comments of third parties

Tags: discussion

There are still the usual new users, who, as they are unable to leave a comment, try to suggest an edit to the OP's question, in order to get their point on to the page...

I recently rejected [this edit](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22212), which was by a third party, who did not have sufficient reputation to comment. The edit actually stated as much:

> EDIT - Not enough points to comment...
>
> I am programming it in Arduino IDE with C. Also, my hardware works
>   fine. I've used it to do other things. The code is what I'm not sure
>   what to do.

If one does not check the identity of the author of the edit carefully - against the identity of the OP - it could be assumed by the reviewer (in *some* cases) that the comment is from the OP (and hence legitimate) in which case, then the edit might be accepted.

As an aside, I am really not sure why new (and inexperienced) users with low reputation are allowed to edit, but not leave a comment, as a bad edit can do much more damage than a bad comment can... but that is a SE issue, in general, and not one that can be resolved on SE Arduino Meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One argument could be that the OP can make edits without needing permission, so you should look more cautiously at suggested edits. It is effectively a red flag that this was **not** the OP. However I'm inclined to agree that if you can't make comments (yet) then you shouldn't be able to slip "comments" in as an edit.